# Backspaced and saved in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, restore, backspace

I was cheerfully coding in **Notepad++**, when someone came up and **backspaced** it all, while I was doing so good! I naturally **save** my code, so before I knew it, that's what I did.  HOW DO I GET IT BACK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to recover an old version from your back up.

If you don't have a backup, then you are likely in for some pain either now or in the future.

In that case, you could try the following:

- right click on the file in Windows Explorer, and select 'Properties' then 'Previous Versions'. If configured right, Windows saves previous versions.
- If the file is in DropBox, log on to the webportal and download a previous version. DropBox saves a few previous versions of files.
- If Notepad++ is still open, try clicking 'Undo', or hitting Ctrl-Z to undo the backspacing